# How can I do datafield access in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am new to Java (knowing OOPS concepts as I am ASP.NET member but not doing Java from last 2 years), creating Tic-Tac-Toe game.

```
Deleted code here as I am putting my code below.
```

Here, I am wondering how below lines are working?

```
game frame = new game();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I understood that frame is Object of game Class and initialized by new game() Constructor but not understanding that how .setVisible() method works for this object.

And one more difficulty I am facing is how can I access initialized objects in other classes or methods.

---

Hello,
I asked previous question because I am facing this difficulty here :
First I'll give code

```
public class Game extends JFrame {


    private JPanel contentPane;
    //private JPanel settingPane;

    protected JLabel lblPlayerName2; // I am using this one for my testing
    JLabel[] lbls = new JLabel[9];
    private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Game frame = new Game();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */

    public Game() {
        setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 810, 607);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        contentPane.setName("Tic Tac Toe");
.       
.
..
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

    for (int i=0; i<lbls.length; i++) {
        lbls[i] = new JLabel(""+(i+1));
        lbls[i].addMouseListener(new AllbtnBehvr());

        lbls[i].setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 95));
        lbls[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbls[i].setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2));
        panelGameArea.add(lbls[i]);
    }
        .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .

    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .

} // End of Game() 

class AllbtnBehvr implements MouseInputListener{ //Created this class as SubClass of Game Class

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent src) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JLabel b = (JLabel) src.getSource();
            lblPlayerName2.setText(b.getText());


.       }
...
.
.
.
.
.
.
} // End of AllbtnBehvr
}// End of Game Class
```

Here, I observed that, variable 'lblPlayerName2' and lbls[] defined outside of Game() Constructor, and it can be accessed, but other variables inside Game() cannot be accessed.
Here, I want to ask,

How can I access to variables inside Game()? and 
How can I access to variables inside Game() if I create class outside Game Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

game extends JFrame, which in turn extends java.awt.Window, so [inherits its methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible%28boolean%29).

PS. Classes should be named with a capital first letter. `Game`.

Comment: Yes I understood that it extends JFrame but how constructor returns JFrame Object specifically?

Comment: It's not the constructor (which in fact does not return anything, behind the scenes it's a void initialization method). The _expression_ new game() returns a game object, which is a JFrame object, and a Window object. All Window objects have setVisible, so the game has setVisible as well.

Comment: Can you give some reference so I can brush up this concept... So how Can I access fields of game() constructor in other method or class(declared inside 'game' class or outside of it ?)

Comment: @HakooDesai [Java Tutorials - Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). Define accessor methods getFoo() and operations, and (better) don't expose the set of fields of the game to the other classes. For example, getSavedGameFile() and setSavedGameFile(), which operate on a JTextField in the game behind the scenes, are preferable to JTextField getSavedGamePathTextField().

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor invocation returns a game object, but since game is derived from JFrame, the object is also a JFrame, a java.awt.Frame, java.awt.Window,  and so on all the way to java.lang.Object.

A sub-class inherits behavior from its super-class, so the setVisible() method defined in java.awt.Window, is available in a game object, which is sub classed from Window, via JFrame.